# Set the selectedValue of drop-down list in a template (on load)

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I'm having some issues with a drop-down list where I need to pass the initial value to the view model so, the drop-down list will be populated with an already-selected value.

This is as far as I got (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdcUA/52/)):

```
var additionalTravellersDetails = [
    { id: 1, firstName: "George", middleName: "", lastName: "Washington ", AcNum: "12345678" }, 
    { id: 2, firstName: "Abraham ", middleName: "", lastName: "Lincoln", AcNum: "23758383" },
    // etc
];

function Traveller(id, AcNum) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.categoryId = ko.observable();
}

Traveller.prototype.getUniqueCategories = function () {
    var thisCategoryId = parseInt(this.categoryId(), 10);
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(additionalTravellersDetails, function (additionalTravellersDetails) {
        return (additionalTravellersDetails.id === thisCategoryId) || !viewModel.usedCategoryIndex()[additionalTravellersDetails.id];
    });
}

var viewModel = {
    TravRows: ko.observableArray([]),
    addTravRow: function () {
        this.TravRows.push(new Traveller());
    },
    removeTravRow: function (Traveller) {
        this.TravRows.remove(Traveller);
    },

    noOfTrav: ko.observableArray(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']),
    SelectedNo: ko.observable('1')
};

viewModel.usedCategoryIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var result = {};
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.TravRows(), function (Traveller) {
        var cat = Traveller.categoryId();
        if (cat) {
            result[cat] = 1;
        }
    });
    return result;
}, viewModel);

viewModel.TravRows.push(new Traveller());

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// On Num of Trav Select index change
$("#nrTravelers").change(function () {
    var len = viewModel.noOfTrav().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        viewModel.removeTravRow(viewModel.TravRows()[0]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
        viewModel.addTravRow();
    }
});
```

And this is the corresponding view:

```html
<p>Number of travellers:
    <select id="nrTravelers" data-bind="options: noOfTrav,  selectedOptions: SelectedNo"></select>
</p>
<table data-bind="template: {name:'AdditionalTravelersTemplate', foreach: TravRows}"></table>
<script id="AdditionalTravelersTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <th>Traveler<span>1</span></th> //TODO: replace 1 with the auto num
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind="options: getUniqueCategories(), 
                               optionsText: function(item) {
                                   return item.lastName+ ' , ' + item.firstName+ ' - '+ item.AcNum }, 
                               optionsValue: 'id', 
                               optionsCaption: 'choose one...', 
                               value: categoryId"></select > 
        </td>
    </tr >
</script>
```

The following are the things I need in the above code:

1. I want to pre populate all the drop-down lists with already selected values
2. When the list does not contain any more travelers, I want to display some text in the drop down list
3. I want to add a number after "Traveler" text for each drop-down list

The 2nd requirement I have [solved](http://jsfiddle.net/vdcUA/56/), two more to go.

PS. I have hard coded some part for the first requirement, please tell me if the approach is OK?

Any suggestions/ideas please?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the first requirement. You want to pre-populate the dropdowns, but with what?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, i will be implementing  this in a popup ..
 so when i open the popup for the second time i want it to be pre-populated with the already selected values

Comment: It seems like you get that for free, just don't mess with the HTML in the popup before you show it again :)

Comment: Ok, but i will be using three such similar popups in the page so i want to store the selected values in a hidden text box or a literal control and populate when the popup is opened again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/P6aDk/

For the index, you could either use `{{each}}` from jQuery template's or an easy way to still get the benefits of KO's `foreach` is to create a manual subscription to your observableArray and update/create a property to hold the position.  This would be like:

```
viewModel.TravRows.subscribe(function(currentValue) {
    for (var i = 0, j = currentValue.length; i < j; i++) {
       var row = currentValue[i];
        if (!row.position) {
           row.position = ko.observable(i+1);  
        } else {
           row.position(i+1);   
        }  
    }
});
```

Now, each row will have a "position" observable that you can bind against and they will stay updated as the array changes.

For, adding/removing rows, you could add a subscription against the `SelectedNo` observable and when it changes you can reconcile the actual number of rows.  Like:

```
viewModel.SelectedNo.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    var actualLen = viewModel.TravRows().length,
        expectedLen = parseInt(newValue, 10);

    if (actualLen < expectedLen) {
        for (var i = actualLen; i < expectedLen; i++) {
           viewModel.addTravRow();  
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = actualLen; i > expectedLen; i--) {
            viewModel.removeTravRow(viewModel.TravRows()[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

For setting existing data, I changed the `value` binding on the dropdown for each row to bind against the `id`.  Then, I set the initial data to include two Travellers with their ids.  You could switch this to account number or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you Ryan for your quick response :)